# Is "need to" a main verb or semi modal?

Tags: grammar

> I **need to do** the work.

In this sentence, which is the main verb? Is it **need** or **do**?

I think the main verb is do and need to is a semi modal. Am I correct?

One of my friends said that **need** is the main verb here and **to do the work** is a *prepositional phrase*. Now I am really confused.

Answer (score 1):

There's no modal or semi-modal verb here.* The main verb is "need" because it's the head of the verb phrase and "to do the work" is what some linguists call a [catenative complement](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-catenative-verb-1689832). "Catenative" means "chaining" and reflects the way that the verb can link recursively with other catenatives to form a chain: e.g. *He needs to try to make him do the work*.

---

*<sub>The modal *need* 1. requires a bare infinitival (infinitive without "to") clause as a complement: e.g. *I need do the work*; 2. It can invert with the subject in the interrogative clause:e.g. *Need I do the work?*; 3. It doesn't require *do* to be negated: e.g. *I need not do the work*.</sub> .